# Is there code sample of using processing.js to visualize microphone input?

Tags: html, google-chrome, visualization, processing.js, web-audio-api

i want to use p5.js to visualize microphone input within a browser(better be chrome).

However, the web audio api https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html drives me crazy cuz it's quite complicated.

i just want to use the sound's amplitude to control the drawing in p5. Just that simple.

Does anybody know if there is any related code sample?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this article can get you the data. You'll have to patch the result into Processing yourself though.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/games/

This function looks at clipping strong signals, but it looks like you should be able to get the audio level.

```
function processAudio(e) {
  var buffer = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

  var isClipping = false;
  // Iterate through buffer to check if any of the |values| exceeds 1.
  for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    var absValue = Math.abs(buffer[i]);
    if (absValue >= 1) {
      isClipping = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in using Processing syntax to visualize microphone input in JS, try [p5.js](http://p5js.org) with the [p5.sound.js](http://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.sound) addon library.

Here's an example measuring amplitude of the p5.AudioIn (http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.AudioIn)

```
var mic;

function setup(){
  mic = new p5.AudioIn()
  mic.start();
}

function draw(){
  micLevel = mic.getLevel();
}
```

You can also easily analyze the frequency spectrum, here's another example
http://p5js.org/learn/examples/Sound_Frequency_Spectrum.php